# Set scale jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Please tell me why I can’t set the scale for the div?

```js
var a = 0.1;
var b = 0.1;
var scale = a+b;
$(".item").css('scale', scale)
```

```css
.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item"></div>
```

Comment: maybe you want `$(".item").css('transform', 'scale(' + scale + ')');`

Comment: References: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scale) and [Can I Use : scale](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_scale)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/css/#css2) :

> When a number is passed as the value, jQuery will convert it to a string and add px to the end of that string. If the property requires units other than px, convert the value to a string and add the appropriate units before calling the method.

Thus, the parameter has to be a string, not a number :

```js
var a = 0.1;
var b = 0.1;
var scale = a+b;
$(".item").css('scale', scale.toString())
```

```css
.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Besides you need to pass as **string** like `` .css("scale", `${scale}`) `` or `.css("scale", scale.toString())` (as already suggested by @Tom),..

you don't need jQuery for that task, just plain JS and CSS Var:

```js
const a = 0.1;
const b = 0.1;
const scale = a + b;

document.querySelectorAll(".item").forEach((elItem) => {
  elItem.style.setProperty("--scale", scale);
});
```

```css
.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  scale: var(--scale, 1); /* Use --scale CSSVar or default to 1 */
}
```

```html
<div class="item"></div>
```

[MDN: Using CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties)
[MDN: CSS var()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var)